# Replace year in string from 1999 to current year (2024) using js regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Can someone suggest me a better way of matching a year in a string between the provided ranges.

A better (shorter) way than this:

```js
let str = 'Document created in 1999';
let str1 = 'Document created in 2000';
let str2 = 'Document created in 2001';

let str_r = str.replaceAll(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ig, '2022');
let str_r1 = str1.replaceAll(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ig, '2023');
let str_r2 = str2.replaceAll(/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/ig, '2024');
console.log('str', str_r);
console.log('str1', str_r1);
console.log('str2', str_r2);
```

Any insight will be appreciated.

Example String

```js
let str = 'Document created in 1999';
let str1 = 'Document created in 2000';
let str2 = 'I was created in 2001';
```

Comment: Trying to cram all of that into a single regex is going to be more complicated and error-prone than just running a simpler regex in a loop over all the years you want to replace. EDIT: I've just reread the question and I'm not even sure that's what you want.

Comment: `better way` - better than what?

Comment: @JaromandaX I seem to be repeating [0-9] a lot lately using regex. so today i was like let me find out if there is a better way than repeating the 0-9 to match each number in a position.

Comment: You mean something like this `/\b\d{4}\b/g`?

Comment: Yes something like that. @MilosStojanovic

Comment: Can you provide small example with one of the strings if possible ? or you can simply explain how the regex is working in short terms.

Comment: `seem to be repeating` nothing at all since you haven't shown any code at all

Comment: @JaromandaX I have updated the Q, Please refresh.

Comment: `/1999|20(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-4])/` or any 4-digit number: `/[0-9]{4}/`

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex with 4 digits between word boundaries and a replacement callback function that checks the year range:

```js
let str = 'Document created in 1999';
let str1 = 'Document created in 2000';
let str2 = 'Document created in 2001';
let str3 = 'Document created in 1998-2008 with 19999 characters';


[str, str1, str2, str3].forEach(str => console.log(
  str.replace(/(?<=\b)\d{4}(?=\b)/g, year => year >= 1999 && year <= new Date().getFullYear() ? '[replacement]' : year)
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment, I don't think a single regex is the best way to do this, but here is a regex matching all years from 1999 to 2024 inclusive.

```
let re = /1999|20[01]\d|202[0-4]/gi;
let str = "Goodbye 1999, hello 2000!"
let newstr = str.replaceAll(re, "new");
console.log(newstr); // Goodbye new, hello new!
```

Better would be to loop over all the years and avoid the potential regex errors altogether.

```
let str = "Goodbye 1999, hello 2000!"
for (let i = 1999; i <= 2024; i++) {
  str = str.replace(i.toString(), "new");
}
console.log(str); // Goodbye new, hello new!
```

Comment: This looks good but is this performant ?

Comment: If you don't want partial matches, you can use word boundaries `\b(?:1999|20[01]\d|202[0-4])\b` and note that you don't need the `/i` flag here.

Comment: @Mwase What make you think it has performance issues? There is nothing about performance in the question. Please do some research on why "premature optimisation" is a bad idea.